# How do I use Redis as the persistence for an Ember Data Store?

Tags: redis, ember-data

How do I use redis as the backend for an ember-data Data Store? It looks like I may need a custom adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Ember is a client-side framework, I would say you need two adapters (server-side and client-side).

The fact is Redis is not designed to be accessed directly over a non secured network. So if your client runs in a browser, you absolutely need a server-side middle-tier between the client and Redis.

One possibility would be to use the [Webdis](http://webd.is/) package as a server-side adapter, and then tweak the JSON/REST [client-side adapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters) provided in Ember data to comply with the Webdis REST-like protocol.